Why is variadic template get error of "no matching function call"
Here is the repro:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
inline void HashCombine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v, const Args& ... args)
{
    seed ^= std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    HashCombine(seed, args...);  // this is line 7
}

inline void HashCombine(std::size_t& seed) {}
    
int main()
{
    std::size_t hash = 0;
    HashCombine(hash);
    HashCombine(hash, 1); // this is line 16: error 
    HashCombine(hash, 1, 2); // error 
    HashCombine(hash, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // error 
    std::cout<< hash;
    
    return 0;
}

I got such error:
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp: In instantiation of 'void HashCombine(std::size_t&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with T = int; Args = {}; std::size_t = long unsigned int]':
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp:16:13:   required from here
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp:7:20: error: no matching function for call to 'HashCombine(std::size_t&)'
    7 |         HashCombine(seed, args...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp:4:13: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class ... Args> void HashCombine(std::size_t&, const T&, const Args& ...)'
    4 | inline void HashCombine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v, const Args& ... args)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp:4:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/AguG0A005j.cpp:7:20: note:   candidate expects at least 2 arguments, 1 provided
    7 |         HashCombine(seed, args...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

What I thought the specializatoin of HashCombine(hash, 1) would be:

void HashCombine(std::size_t&, const T&, const Args& ...) [with T = int; Args = {};]
void HashCombine(std::size_t&), however, it seems the termination failed to reach here

What is the reason of this error?

Move the non-template one-parameter overload before the template one. You are trying to call it before it was declared.

That's correct, what a mistake. Thanks @IgorTandetnik
